# Silverlight Style : custom style based on custom style

Tags: silverlight, controltemplate

Someone has done a custom style for the buttons of the application. Now I want to create a custom style based on this custom style. For example I want to make a "close button" that I want to reuse all other the application. I tried this :

```
<Style x:Key="GlassButtonClose" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlassButton}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="/Balisage;component/Images/Close.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocCommonStrings}, Path=ButtonLabelClose}" Margin="0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But this doesn't keep the GlassButton settings. How can I just extend the settings, keeping the existing ones ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which "GlasButton" settings do you want to keep? You are overwriting the `HorizontalAlignment` and the `Template` (and therefore all defined `VisualStates`).

Comment: Thanks, it's what I understand, but I don't know how two keep existing visual states and add new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the shown template and your answer in the comments it looks like you only need to have a spacific GlassButton with a fixed icon and text. And you want to use this button without the need to specify its content again and again.

**Solution:**
Prepare your own type `GlassStyleCloseButton`.

```
public class GlassStyleCloseButton : Button
{
    public GlassStyleCloseButton() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(GlassStyleCloseButton); }
}
```

and a style for the new type (can be placed in app.xaml or generic.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="GlassStyleCloseButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlassButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonLabelClose,
        Source={StaticResource LocCommonStrings}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image
                    Source="/Balisage;component/Images/Close.png"
                    Width="24"
                    Height="24"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and you can use it like this:

```
<SomewhereInMyApp>
    ...
    <GlassStyleCloseButton/>
</SomewhereInMyApp>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the ContentTemplate was what I was looking for. Just one thing, the TemplateBinding is not working and I have to put the real binding to see the text, do you know why ?

Comment: Never mind, I've found the solution, I use a normal binding with RelativeSource TemplatedParent to see the text.